# Correct JPA Annotation for PostgreSQL's text type without Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I'm developing an application using:

- Java 1.7
- JPA (included in javaee-api 7.0)
- Hibernate 4.3.8.Final
- PostgreSQL-JDBC 9.4-1200-jdbc41
- PostgreSQL 9.3.6

And I would like to use the PostgreSQL text datatype for some String attributes. As far as I know, in JPA this should be the correct annotation, to use text in PostgreSQL:

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    ...
    @Lob
    private String description;
    ....
}
```

When I annotate my entity like this, I run into errors which look like this:
http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html

In short: It seems that hibernate and jdbc go not hand in hand for clob/text-types.

The solution described is working:

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    ...
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

But this has a significant downside: The source code needs hibernate at compile time, which should be unnecessary (That's one reason for using JPA in the first place).

Another way is to use the column annotation like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    ...
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

Which works nicely, BUT: 
Now I'm stuck with databases which have a text type (and is also called text ;) ) and if another database will be used in the future the annotations can be overlooked easily. Thus the possible error can be hard to find, because the datatype is defined in a String and therefore can not be found before runtime.

Is there a solution, which is so easy, I just don't see it? I'm very sure that I'm not the only one using JPA in combination with Hibernate and PostgreSQL. So I'm a little confused that I can't find more questions like this.

Just to complete the question, the persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="entityManager">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.app.model.Product</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/awesomedb" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="usr" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
      <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**UPDATE:**

- This problem is more or less equivalent with this question, the picked answer is the second way to do it described in this question, which I don't like due to the hibernate runtime dependency:
  [store strings of arbitrary length in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158645/store-strings-of-arbitrary-length-in-postgresql)
- This seems to be kind of related to: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-48

Comment: Since you're talking about what's really a deployment issue (auto-generated DDL), can't you just manually create the table as TEXT in Postgres and just not specify anything in the class?

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to generate the DB from hibernate.

Comment: So...you want to use a non-standard SQL feature but don't want to risk incompatibility with databases that don't have the non-standard feature?

Comment: @chrylis When you say it like this, it sounds wrong :D
My prefered way would be I use the annotations in the JPA-way described in the first place (Simply `@Lob`). And let hibernate/jdbc do the magic in the background. Like I know, an `@Lob String` should result in `clob` in DB2, Oracle, `longvarchar` in H2/HSQLDB, `longtext` or `text` in MySQL and `text` in PostgreSQL.
My problem is, that hibernate and postgresql jdbc create an error, where should not be any issue.

Comment: But text and lob *aren't* the same thing semantically.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, you can add the `@Lob` to more types, that's right. But as far as I know, the type of an `@Lob` annotated String should result in the postgresql type text. At production that's the case in point. But I can not access the generated database field because hibernate and jdbc driver do not engage with each other. It should not matter that text is not SQL standard in the first place.

Comment: I was looking for the opposite you wanted and your question was my answer. Curious. I just added the `columnDefinition = "text"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since the `text` type is not a part of the SQL standard there is no official JPA way I guess.

However, the `text` type is quite similar to `varchar`, but without the length limit. You can hint the JPA implementation with the `length` property of `@Column`:

```java
@Column(length=10485760)
private String description;
```

**Update:** 10 MiB seems to be the maximum length for `varchar` in postgresql. The `text` is *almost* unlimited, according the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html):

> In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored
>   is about 1 GB.

Comment: Yes, this will works in most cases, when the table should not be generated by the application. It results in a PostgreSQL column type varchar(1000000000). Which is limited, the text type is defined to store text without any limitation.

Comment: As far as I know Hibernate and PostgreSQL's jdbc driver, are not really compatible to each other at this point, hibernate tries to get a clob, because the lob annotation and the jdbc driver offers the content of the lob not the address. I don't know which is the right way, but the definitely should arrange a solution, so the end user can use this stuff. Because it's just ugly to stumble into this problem.

Comment: @knoe: You can also use `varchar` without a limit in Postgres. In Postgres there is really no difference at all between `text` or `varchar` so just go with whatever the obfuscation layer works best with

Comment: @holmis83 BTW: I tried this just now, and I get this:
`PSQL ERROR: length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760`

@a_horse_with_no_name Yes, this is quite the same as to use the `@Column(columnDefinition="text")`, when I get you right. This would be the same as solution two from the original question.

Comment: @knoe Updated my answer. I would not recommend auto-generated DDL for a production system.

Comment: Okay, this works. It is limited and in my opinion not really a nice way. But I appreciate your help! It seems, that there's no other way which I have overlooked, maybe I should contact the hibernate/jdbc-driver developers.

Comment: I also face this situation, I go with columnDefinition and force all to text and get rid of any kind of varchar, char. I take the burden of vendor specific data type, but it is not big deal for me as we have only single candidate when using RDBMS -> PostgreSQL, other solutions are gone. Actually I hope there will be no char, varchar in future and just text :-)

Answer (score 6):

I just had to add this annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

It did not work on its own. I had to recreate the table in the database.

`DROP TABLE yourtable` or just alter column type to `text` with `ALTER TABLE` statement

Comment: For me the uppercase TEXT did not work with postgres, it had to be all lowercase, otherwise I got the error message `ERROR:  type "TEXT" does not exist at character`. This worked: 

`@Column(columnDefinition="text")`

Comment: This worked for me (uppercase and lower) and I did not have to recreate the table. (postgres 13)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use plain JPA you could just remap the used CLOB type on the Dialect like this:

```
public class PGSQLMapDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {


  @Override
  public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (Types.CLOB == sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType()) {
      return LongVarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }
    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
  }


}
```

So it won't use the CLOB mapping from the JDBC driver which uses a OID for the column and stores/loads the text via large object handling.
This would just result in setString and getString calls on the createt text column on the Postgres JDBC Driver via the VarcharTypeDescriptor class.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll give it a try. 

But I still don't see why this should be needed at all.

Comment: You don't need it - it works already using CLOB from the JDBC Driver with OIDs to work with the String. If you want to change that it would be better addressed at the JDBC Driver - imho Hibernate is fine here.

Comment: The downside of just using the "works already" CLOB like this is extremely poor performance - imho this is not fine

Comment: It may not be fine, but its not hibernates responsibility to fix that - that's why i did write you should address this to the jdbc driver developers.

Comment: Please explain how to wire this in - I think this will help me run JUnit tests with Derby, and deploy to MariaDB, with MariadDB column type definition annotations in the code.

Comment: Just write your custom dialect class and set the hibernate property "hibernate.dialect" to use your new dialect class (can be seen in the OP configuration above).

Answer (score 3):

I would go with simple `private String description;`. The column type is only a problem if you are generating the database from your code, because it will be generated as `varchar` instead of `text`.

It is great to code in database agnostic way, and without any JPA vendor specific things, but there are cases where this just isn't possible. If the reality is that you will have to support multiple database types with all their specifics, then you have to account for those specifics somewhere. One option is to use `columnDefinition` for defining column type. Another is to leave the code as it is, and just change the column type in the database. I prefer the second one.

Comment: Yes, I want to generate DB from code. 
If I wouldn't need it. I figured out, that 
   @Column(columnDefinition = "longvarchar")
    private String description;
    Would just work fine, because the hibernate/jdbc driver combination then expects text and not a clob-address. Which is the problem with the long/text error from the link. But the table creation would just fail, because postgresql doesn't know the type longvarchar. If I could define an alias like longvarchar=text in PostgreSQL by myself, this could be interesting...

Comment: Which is more or less, the same as your solution, because the columnDefiniton is only used at table definition.

Comment: @knoe: there is absolutely no difference between `varchar` and `text` in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's right, but the generated column for a String without annotation is varchar(255) but I don't want it to be limited, that is the problem in the first place.