# Hibernate with Postgresql not loading the data correctly for column with 'text' datatype

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, liquibase

I have following entity and some sample data is being loaded using liquibase `loadData`

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="my_text")
    private String myText;
}
```

To load sample data using liquibase, following csv file has been used.

```
id;my_text

1;referenceToFile
```

And the content of `referenceToFile`

```
This is a very large text
```

The liquibase definition is as following:

```
<changeSet id="123455-1-data" author="user">
    <loadData
              file="config/liquibase/data/myentity.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="myentity">
        <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
        <column name="my_text" type="blob"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

However, when loading data using hibernate, I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:306)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 165 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : This is a very large text
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:2873)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2099)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getClob(PgResultSet.java:459)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getClob(PgResultSet.java:445)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getClob(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3010)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1746)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    ... 196 common frames omitted
```

Then I came across this site http://www.solewing.org/blog/2015/08/hibernate-postgresql-and-lob-string/ where it says postgres stores `text` somewhere else and keep a `long` reference. But liquibase seems inserting directly the text value rather than complying with postgres `text` type.

My question is how can we load the data correctly using liquibase for `text` type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588311/correct-jpa-annotation-for-postgresqls-text-type-without-hibernate-annotations

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in the past, I used clob instead of blob and it solved my problem