# Get TEXT column value in psql

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, psql

I have created simple entity with Hibernate with `@Lob String` field. Everything works fine in Java, however I am not able to check the values directly in DB with `psql` or `pgAdmin`.

Here is the definition from DB:

```
=> \d+ user_feedback
                    Table "public.user_feedback"
 Column |  Type  | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | bigint | not null  | plain    |              | 
 body   | text   |           | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "user_feedback_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Has OIDs: no
```

And here is that I get from select:

```
=> select * from user_feedback;
 id | body  
----+-------
 34 | 16512
 35 | 16513
 36 | 16514
(3 rows)
```

The actual "body" content is for all rows "normal" text, definitely not these numbers.

How to retrieve actual value of `body` column from psql?

Comment: @Lob  is an annotation that saves the data as clob or blob, speaking of java it should be an array of bytes or chars, therefore you are saving some info about that array on the field in postgresql I do not know which value. Try to change your annotation to string equivalent. It should work. See a reference here: http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/lob-hibernate-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store the content of LOB 16512 in file out.txt :

```
\lo_export 16512 out.txt
```

Although using @Lob is usually not recommended here (database backup issues ...). See [store-strings-of-arbitrary-length-in-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158645/store-strings-of-arbitrary-length-in-postgresql) for alternatives.

Comment: thanks, I can get to "my content" :) I tried to used generic solution, however I will consider your suggestion since I don't expect to change postgresql soon.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is storing the values as out-of-line objects in the `pg_largeobject` table, and storing the Object ID for the `pg_largeobject` entry in your table. See [PostgreSQL manual - large objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html).

It sounds like you expected inline byte array (`bytea`) storage instead. If so, you may want to map a `byte[]` field *without* a `@Lob` annotation, rather than a `@Lob String`. Note that this change will *not be backward compatible* - you'll have to export your data from the database then drop the table and re-create it with Hibernate's new definition.

The selection of how to map your data is made by Hibernate, not PostgreSQL.

See related:

- [proper hibernate annotation for byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3677380/398670)
- [How to store image into postgres database using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10671471/398670)