# PostgreSQL values of column (type text) are shown as numbers

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a table Campaign_actions which has a column `terms` with type text.
Today I noticed that all text in the column `terms` are changed to numbers:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like OIDs - Hibernate is famous for not being able to properly work with `text` columns. It always (incorrectly) thinks it needs to treat them as "large objects". How was the data stored in that table?

Comment: data is stored through java Api (hibernate).

Comment: Did you tag that column with `@Lob`? If yes, you should tag with `@String`

Comment: Java Api still works correctly, data is taken as text

Comment: Hibernate stupidly uses the large objects interface which is a total waste for `text` columns (and incorrect to begin with). The correct way to work with `text` columns in JDBC is to use `PreparedStatement.setString()` and `ResultSet.getString()`

Comment: Yes i have "@Lob" on property. Does hibernate have "@String " annotation?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158645) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588311) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512771)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use hibernate annotations in java, you need to specify type of Lob. Example:

```
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    String largeText;
```